# CSS selecting a div after a div with a div

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I have this code on a login page:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="homeBanner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    ...
</div>
```

I'd like to select div#navigation but only when it follows div#header that contains div#homeBanner. The reason is I have similar code on a different page:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="siteBanner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    ...
</div>
```

I don't want to affect the style of div#navigation when it follows div#header that contains div#siteBanner. Does this make sense?

How do I select div#navigation only when it follows div#header that contains div#homeBanner? I thought it was:

```
div#header div#homeBanner > div#navigation
```

... but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That means "inside `div#header`, the first `div#navigation` after a `div#homeBanner`".

Comment: You're right. I also tried `(div#header div#homeBanner) + div#navigation` but that didn't work either!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem here is that you're trying to select the sibling of a parent element based on the parent's child, which isn't possible in CSS.

Your best bet is to add a class to `#header` (or even `body`) based on that information then make use of that class.

For example:

```
<div id="header" class="home">
    <div id="homeBanner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    ...
</div>
```

With this selector (as mentioned by others, use `+` for siblings, not `>` for children):

```
#header.home + #navigation
```

Comment: To apply the class dynamically with jQuery, use `$('#header:has(#homeBanner)').addClass('home');`

Comment: Or even more simply, do everything in jQuery, because all the cool kids do everything in jQuery: `$('#header:has(#homeBanner) + #navigation').css(/* Do things that you're supposed to do with CSS but aren't doing because you're cool and everything */);`

Comment: Good call on the jQuery. I think I will implement a new class, even though I was trying to avoid that, since it seems to be the more logical approach and my colleagues tend to frown on jQuery hacks :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code:

```
div#header + div#navigation
```

Use the + for sibblings.

Comment: Tried it to no avail. You're right on the use of + over > though. I got those mixed up.

Comment: That selects `#navigation` that comes after `#homeBanner`, not `#header`.